# How can I get consistent results for my error messages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cherrypy

I have the following little script running as a standalone app based on [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) 3.2.2 (alright, actually it's a condensed version to demonstrate what I'm trying to correct):

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import _cperror

class MyApp:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    if ('recursive' in kwargs) and kwargs['recursive']:
      return
    cherrypy.tree.mount(MyApp(recursive=True), '/cgi-bin', {})

  def error_page(status, message, traceback, version):
    error_template = """\
<html><head><title>%s</title></head>
<body><h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p></body>
</html>"""
    return error_template % (status, status, message)

  @cherrypy.expose
  def script_name(self, **kwargs):
    return str(kwargs)

  favicon_ico = None
  _cp_config = {'error_page.404' : error_page}

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(
      MyApp(),
      config = {
        'global':{
          'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0',
          'server.socket_port':8080,
          }})
```

When I fetch a URL underneath `/cgi-bin` or generally anywhere, I will get the expected:

> **404 Not Found**
>
> The path '/' was not found.

however, when I fetch anything that passes a "`PATH_INFO`" such as `/cgi-bin/script_name/foobar` I get:

> **404 Not Found**
>
> Nothing matches the given URI

How can I ensure that in the latter case I get the same error message (only variable being the actual path mentioned in the message) as in the former, while still being able to serve content under the URI `/cgi-bin/script_name`?